# How to parse a txt file for a dynamic lines with changing index in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I am new to Python . 
need to parse a text file with dynamic variable (changing index)  .

I am having the following text file

```
packet1_ref_time = 13.64
packet2_ref_time = 73.68
16.11.2018 16:33:03 {Step 1 passed successfully!}
16.11.2018 16:33:06 {}
packet1_ref_time = 17.25
packet2_ref_time = 71.112
16.11.2018 16:33:03 {Step 2 Failed!}
16.11.2018 16:33:06 {}
packet1_ref_time = 13.877
packet2_ref_time = 78.366
16.11.2018 16:33:03 {Step 3 passed successfully!}
16.11.2018 16:33:06 {}
```

my final output \ another text file should be: 
Test 1 passed
Test 2 failed
Test 3 Passed

```
def main():
    file = open("Console_log_28-12-2018_02-31-55.txt","r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    for line in lines:
        line=line.strip()
        index = 1
        str (index)
        #if line == "Step"index"passed successfully!":
        if line.find("Step 1 passed successfully!") != -1:
           print ( line )
main()
```

result is "28.12.2018 02:36:16 {Step 1 passed successfully!}" 
as expected . 
and its obvious as I am searching for an exact step (step 1 in this case) 
and what I need it to search for a dynamic index just as I've written in the comment : 
 #if line == "Step"index"passed successfully!":

however I just can;t find the correct syntax on how to code it .

Comment: Does the log file have a constant 4 lines for every step? If so you can just get every fourth line and print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
outputlist = []
with open("Console_log_28-12-2018_02-31-55.txt","r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if 'passed successfully' in line:
            loc = line.find('passed')
            test, num = 'pass', line[:loc].split()[-1]
            outputlist.append((num, test))
        elif 'Failed' in line:
            loc = line.find('Failed')
            test, num = 'fail', line[:loc].split()[-1]
            outputlist.append((num, test))

print (outputlist)
#[('1', 'pass'), ('2', 'fail'), ('3', 'pass')]
```

Explanation:
`test, num = 'pass', line[:loc].split()[-1]` will get for you the last number in the line that is detected to have the condition fulfilled. This helps you account for as many test cases as possible so long as they are split by a .
`outputlist` is a list of tuples in which it will tell you which test cases have pass or fail.

So you can then do a for loop in outputlist to print out the statements you require.

```
for i, v in outputlist:
    print (f'Test {i} {v}ed')
#Test 1 passed
#Test 2 failed
#Test 3 passed
```

Also, use `with` to open your files so that you can skip having to call `f.close()`. `with` will invoke the dunder method `__exit__` to help close the file

Answer (score 1):

For finding lines you can use regular expression i.e. `re` module

```
for line in lines:
    if bool(re.search('Step [0-9]+ (passed successfully)|(Failed)!',line)):
        print(line)
```

`[0-9]+` means any natural number, while `|` means or in `re` in this case `passed succsssfully` or `Failed`.

EDIT: After rethinking your question I concluded `re.findall` would be even better, see my examplle below

```
text = '''better in this case
packet1_ref_time = 13.64
packet2_ref_time = 73.68
16.11.2018 16:33:03 {Step 1 passed successfully!}
16.11.2018 16:33:06 {}
packet1_ref_time = 17.25
packet2_ref_time = 71.112
16.11.2018 16:33:03 {Step 2 Failed!}
16.11.2018 16:33:06 {}
packet1_ref_time = 13.877
packet2_ref_time = 78.366
16.11.2018 16:33:03 {Step 3 passed successfully!}
16.11.2018 16:33:06 {}'''
tests = re.findall('Step [0-9]+ passed|Step [0-9]+ Failed',text)
print(tests)
```

Output:

```
['Step 1 passed', 'Step 2 Failed', 'Step 3 passed']
```

Note that for clarity I simply assigned string to `text`. You should assign value returned by `.read()` to your variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatting operator along with the string argument to find function as mentioned below. String formatting operator can be used wherever we need any replacements in the string.

```
def main():
    file = open("Console_log_28-12-2018_02-31-55.txt","r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    for line in lines:
        line=line.strip()
        index = 1
        str (index)
        #if line == "Step"index"passed successfully!":
        if line.find("Step %d passed successfully!"%index) != -1:
           print ( line )
main()
```

To know more about this, please see documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations